# How to calculate lattice hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, crystals, lattice-model

I was watching White's DMRG introduction video on youtube, where he was showing the 1D lattice model as an example. He said that it's hamiltonian is (ignoring the constant factors)
$$H = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$$
And if we put it in the lattice, we get that the hamiltonian is (ignoring the $1/a^2$ factor):
$$H = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots  \\
-1 & 2  & -1 & 0 &\cdots \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here is the video, with the matrix on the table: [The Density Matrix Renormalization Group I - White](https://youtu.be/4bCFXBYIdMY?t=1792)

How did he get this form? And "what does it do"?

My idea was that maybe it's the second quantized form of the hamiltonian, but that can't be, as it would be diagonal, i.e.
$$H=\sum_{i,j}a^\dagger_i a_j H_{i,j}$$
then $H_{i,j}$ will be proportional to $\delta_{i,j}$,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is  just a discretized version of $-\partial_x^2$. Define a vector ${\bf x}=x_n$ where $n$ in the site, then in ${\bf y}=H{\bf x}$ the vector $y$ has components
$$
y_n=(x_{n+1}- x_n) - (x_n-x_{n-1})= x_{n+1}-2x_n + x_{n-1},
$$
which being the difference of two differences approximates the second derivative.